# Select <p> from HTML using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to get the paragraphs under this tag:

[image]

** if you would like to see how it looks like under the tag: [HERE](http://postimg.org/image/b5olmr86h/)

I tried to:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.21 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1042.0 Safari/535.21").get();
Elements a = doc.select("p#dev-content");
Elements b = doc.select("dev-content");
Elements c = doc.select("p#dev-content.details-text.ng-binding");
Elements d = doc.select("dev-content.details-text.ng-binding");
Elements e = doc.select("p.details-text.ng-binding");
```

But unfortunately none worked.

I also tried:

```
Elements f = doc.select("p");
```

And I got the paragraphs I wanted along with unwanted ones, and they were duplicated.

** if you would like to visit the site I tried on: [HERE](https://sabq.org/%D8%B4%D8%A7%D9%87%D8%AF-%D8%A3%D9%84%D9%81-%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D8%A9-%D8%AA%D8%B1%D9%88%D9%8A-%D9%82%D8%B5%D8%B5-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%B1%D9%85%D9%8A%D9%86-%D9%85%D9%86%D8%B0-%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%B7%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%82-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D9%87%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D8%B9%D9%88%D8%AF%D9%8A)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site you're targeting loads its data with AngularJS. This is why Jsoup was unable to locate the correct paragraph.

Hopefully, the content you're looking for is located on the page as a JSON string.

Here is a sample code for extracting this data:

#### SAMPLE CODE

```
// Fetch the document
Document doc = Jsoup //
        .connect("https://sabq.org/%D8%B4%D8%A7%D9%87%D8%AF-%D8%A3%D9%84%D9%81-%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D8%A9-%D8%AA%D8%B1%D9%88%D9%8A-%D9%82%D8%B5%D8%B5-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%B1%D9%85%D9%8A%D9%86-%D9%85%D9%86%D8%B0-%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%B7%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%82-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D9%87%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D8%B9%D9%88%D8%AF%D9%8A") //
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.21 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1042.0 Safari/535.21") //
        .get();

// Look for the script containing the JSON data
Elements scripts = doc.select("script[data-cfasync=false]");
String content = null;
for (Element script : scripts) {
    String scriptText = script.html();
    if (scriptText.contains("dataFirstLoad")) {
        String dataFirstLoad = scriptText.replaceAll("(?i)^[\\s\\S]*dataFirstLoad\\s*=\\s*(\\{.+\\})\\s*;[\\s\\S]*$", "$1");

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(dataFirstLoad);

        content = json.getJSONObject("material").getString("content");

        break;
    }
}

// Show content
System.out.println("Extracted content:\n" + content);
```

#### OUTPUT (stripped)

```
Extracted content:
<p><span style="color:#FF0000;">(تصوير :فايز الزيادي،عبدالله النحيط) :</span> تتزاحم في جناح رئاسة الحرمين الشريفين وفي مساحة صغيرة لا تتجاوز بضعة أمتار على أرض معرض الرياض الدولي للكتاب، 16 ألف ورقة، ينبعث من حروفها رحيق الطُهر لت(...)    </p>  <p> </p>
```

#### DEPENDENCIES

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20160212</version>
</dependency>
```

#### REFERENCES

- [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)
- [JSON-java](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java)